# How i can use combobox.selectedvalue in SQL query in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I use `combobox.SelectedValue` in SQL query in C#?

```
using (OracleDB db = new OracleDB())
{
    if (name.Checked)
    {
        DataTable nameDT= db.Select("SELECT name FROM People where name= IN THIS PLACE I NEED SELECTED VALUE FROM COMBOBOX1"), "Osoby");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (OracleDB db = new OracleDB())
{
    if (name.Checked)
    {
        var sql = String.Format("Select [name] FROM People WHERE [name] = {0}", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        var nameDT = db.Select(sql, "Osoby");
    }
}
```

[MSDN: ComboBox.SelectedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
"...where name=" + comboBoxName.SelectedValue.ToString()), "Osoby");
```

Comment: This should be a comment more than an answer. Please re-word it.

Comment: It would have been a comment, however I do not have commenting privileges.

Such a simple question requires a simple answer. I will re-word it.

Comment: Not a C# expert, but do the SQL connection classes not have bind variables?

Comment: You can bind to properties in SQL Connection classes, however the UI will not be notified when their properties are changed as they do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

It might be worth checking this tutorial for more information on INotifyPropertyChanged: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)